# Good Swing LayoutManager for Window Builder

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

As to my experience in my Java Swing programming, I have only used absolute layout, in which I can position objects anywhere in frame using a Window Builder plugin for Eclipse. But the problem with that is, it's hard to maintain, and when the frame is re-sized the objects remain in their positions which is a not good.

Is there a layout manager in Swing that uses absolute positioning (I'm using Window Builder) but when the frame is resized, the objects inside the frame go with the flow?

Comment: *"is there a layout manager in java swing that uses absolute positioning(im using windowbuilder) but when the frame is resized, the objects inside the frame also goes with the flow?"*  How exactly would you code the logic of that?  Get used to using *[combinations of layout managers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556)* along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this site, I have been using it for  some time and I am very please,

http://www.miglayout.com/